# How do I parse a string with 'h', 'm', 's' suffixes to a TimeSpan?

Tags: c#, .net, string, parsing, timespan

I need to parse the string `"26h44m3s"` to  a `TimeSpan` in C#. I cannot find anything implemented in .NET that can handle it. So how do I accomplish it, and in clean way? And are there any existing nugets for this?

I am receiving the string from the "duration" property on Twitch API endpoint [GetVideos](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference#get-videos).

Comment: `Regex.Match("26h44m32s", @"(?<hours>\d\d?)h(?<minutes>\d\d?)m(?<seconds>\d\d?)s")` perhaps?

Comment: Have you tried using `TimeSpan.ParseExact`?  You just have to delimit the "h", "m", and "s" with a backslash for it to work.

Comment: @juharr: I tried that; 26 is out of range for hours.

Comment: You could parse this into a `Duration` in Noda Time, then convert that to a `TimeSpan` if you really want (or just keep using Noda Time :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh yeah, that's kinda annoying (the parsing thing, not Noda Time).

Comment: @JonSkeet
Thanks. Will Noda Time manage the 26 hour range? Btw I made a solution I don't exactly love:
https://gist.github.com/lindeberg/d0730c99b1d9e799f2f38c16242c1a31

Comment: @Lindeberg: Yes, Noda Time will cope with that just fine if you pass it the right format. Do you want me to add that as an answer? (I'm reluctant to plug Noda Time too much in answers when it's not otherwise mentioned ;)

Comment: @JonSkeet Please do!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by using regex parsing without any external dependencies:

```
public static TimeSpan ParseTwitchTime(string input)
{
    var m = Regex.Match(input, @"^((?<hours>\d+)h)?((?<minutes>\d+)m)?((?<seconds>\d+)s)?$", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.RightToLeft);

    int hs = m.Groups["hours"].Success ? int.Parse(m.Groups["hours"].Value) : 0;
    int ms = m.Groups["minutes"].Success ? int.Parse(m.Groups["minutes"].Value) : 0;
    int ss = m.Groups["seconds"].Success ? int.Parse(m.Groups["seconds"].Value) : 0;

    return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(hs*60*60 + ms*60 + ss);
}
```

Usage:

```
        var d = ParseTwitchTime("100h");
        d = ParseTwitchTime("23m1000s");
        d = ParseTwitchTime("12345h678s");
```

PS: RightToLeft option used just for regex performance and not affecting output result (it backtracks a lot if done without it).

Comment: Oh neat! Just needs some modification since i forgot to mention that the identifiers are optional. These are also being returned and has to be parsed:
"26h8m" 
"26h"
"15s"
"56m47s"

Comment: Not a problem. Wait a second until I correct answer.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org) for this, parsing as a `Duration`. You *could* then convert it to a `TimeSpan` - or you could use Noda Time everywhere and have a nicer experience :)

Sample code:

```
using System;
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string text = "26h44m3s";
        var pattern = DurationPattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("H'h'm'm's's'");
        var duration = pattern.Parse(text).Value;
        Console.WriteLine(duration);
        var ts = duration.ToTimeSpan();
        Console.WriteLine(ts);
    }
}
```

If you have multiple patterns that need to match, you can create a composite pattern - although you'll need to list all the patterns explicitly. Here's an example of that:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        string[] formats =
        {
            "H'h'm'm's's'", "H'h'm'm'", "M'm's's'", "H'h'", "M'm'", "S's'"
        };
        var patterns = formats.Select(DurationPattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture);
        var builder = new CompositePatternBuilder<Duration>();
        foreach (var pattern in patterns)
        {            
            // The second parameter is used to choose which pattern is
            // used for formatting. Let's ignore it for now.
            builder.Add(pattern, _ => true);
        }
        var composite = builder.Build();


        string[] values = { "26h8m", "26h", "15s", "56m47s" };
        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(composite.Parse(value).Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I dislike how all types of different formats have to be specified even though the value string offers enough information to not need any of them. You can check out my answer that eliminates the problem.

Comment: @Despacito2: I prefer to be very explicit in what I'll accept. Note that your code would allow things like `15h5000m` which I'd prefer to throw an exception as being invalid (at least in most cases).

Comment: I see your point. But TimeSpan.From[Insert time period here] also supports going beyond the limit of each time period so that you could write `TimeSpan.FromHours(15) + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5000)` and wouldn't be forced to do `TimeSpan.FromDays(4) + TimeSpan.FromHours(2) + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20)`. Either way I would find it more intuitive if it was possible to set an array of single format segments like `string[] formats = { "H'h", "m'm", "s's"}` to allow all types of order combinations so that you weren't forced to set all of them manually

Comment: @Despacito2: Yes, `TimeSpan.FromMinutes` allows that, but it doesn't mean it should be valid in a text representation (beyond the leading value). I still think having the full set of valid formats declaratively is better than just mix and match. (I don't think `47s56m` should be valid, for example. I would prefer that to be rejected.)

Comment: That's reasonable to prefer and in that case you're right.

Comment: For future users reading this. Jon Skeet is 100% right. I originally came from a question that desired a **manual** input of the same format to create a `TimeSpan` and therefore was looking for an answer where the values could go beyond the cap. I was looking for duplicate questions and found this, thinking it's the same thing. But since this question focuses on an input from the API where the format would always be consistent (never go beyond the cap except for the leading value and the time periods would be in descending order), this answer should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a custom method to allow you to do that:

```
public static class TimeSpanHelper
{
    private static List<(string Abbreviation, TimeSpan InitialTimeSpan)> timeSpanInfos = new List<(string Abbreviation, TimeSpan InitialTimeSpan)>
    {
            ("y", TimeSpan.FromDays(365)), // Year
            ("M", TimeSpan.FromDays(30)), // Month
            ("w", TimeSpan.FromDays(7)), // Week
            ("d", TimeSpan.FromDays(1)), // Day
            ("h", TimeSpan.FromHours(1)), // Hour
            ("m", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)), // Minute
            ("s", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)), // Second
            ("t", TimeSpan.FromTicks(1)) // Tick
    };

    public static TimeSpan ParseDuration(string format)
    {
        var result = timeSpanInfos
            .Where(timeSpanInfo => format.Contains(timeSpanInfo.Abbreviation))
            .Select(timeSpanInfo => timeSpanInfo.InitialTimeSpan * int.Parse(new Regex(@$"(\d+){timeSpanInfo.Abbreviation}").Match(format).Groups[1].Value))
            .Aggregate((accumulator, timeSpan) => accumulator + timeSpan);
        return result;
    }
}
```

You can use it in the following way:

```
var total = TimeSpanHelper.ParseDuration("26h44m3s");
```